# NodeJS Server - Multiple URL Rewrite Config

Tags: node.js, express, url-rewriting, alias

I'm looking to use a NodeJS server as a temporary solve to test some AngularJS apps that were built in a .NET environment *(I'm on a mac)*. Both apps use the `<base>` tag and the web.config has rewrite rules to avoid 404's on refresh, etc.

I found a potential approach discussed [here](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/07/26/angularjs-enable-html5-mode-page-refresh-without-404-errors-in-nodejs-and-iis), however, I'm having trouble updating the example to includes multiple rules.

The **dir structure** I'm trying to test looks something like this:

```
|-- global (both apps use assets located inside of global)
|-- apps
    |-- myApp1
    |-- myApp2
```

The apps themselves use ***relative to root*** paths for all assets. So, for example:

**myApp1:**

```
/global/images/image.jpg
/apps/myApp1/images/image.jpg
/apps/myApp1/css/styles.css
/apps/myApp1/js/scripts.js
```

The following rules are depicted in the **web.config**:

```
    <rule name="AngularJS Route for myApp1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^myApp1/.*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/apps/myApp1/default.aspx" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="AngularJS Route for myApp2" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^myApp2/.*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/apps/myApp2/default.aspx" />
    </rule>
```

Both apps can be accessed using their respective ***aliases:***

```
mydomain.com/myApp1/
mydomain.com/myApp2/
```

So, with that said, I'm trying to create a very simple nodejs server to emulate the above and am not looking for something that will run a production ready server. Just something I can spin up anytime this client sends me stuff to test.

I started looking at a few links, like the one [above](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/07/26/angularjs-enable-html5-mode-page-refresh-without-404-errors-in-nodejs-and-iis), but am having a hard time figuring out how I could do it with multiple rewrites using the code below:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.url === 'myApp1') {

        //what do I do here?
        //tell it to reference the orig path?

        req.url = '/apps/myApp1/'; 

        //or do I use the router approach that's discussed in my reference link above?
    }

    next();
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000')
});
```

It seems like this question is asked a lot, but I have yet to see it applied to multiple rewrites, while also keeping in mind a shared global dir that both apps pull from. Anyone ever had to do anything like this before?

Answer (score 0):

Think I figured it out. Here's my solve for those looking at this in the future. Not sure if it's the best method, but it seems to be working for me:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();

const static = router.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/', { redirect: false }));

const app1 = router.get('/myApp1*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('apps/myApp1/index.html'));
});

const app2 = router.get('/myApp2*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('apps/myApp2/index.html'));
});

app.use(static, app1, app2);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
```